# String Filtering.Need to remove the <style> tag and its contents and keep only the contents in <body>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

In our project, we are getting a response from the DB. We are using the same string in two ways.

1. We have to display the text part alone in one line
2. We are putting the entire content as an HTML.

We are getting a response similar to this.

```
"<html><head><title>SomeTitle</title></head><style>a.hover{color:green}cc.a{color:red},pq.a{text-decoration:underline}</style> <body> Some content </body></html>"
```

I need to get the content only from the body using string manipulation.I need to filter out all the contents of the other tags as well.

For example 
Final result should be

```
Some content
```

I used text() in some case but at times the content inside  is also getting displayed. That is not allowed for me.

Note: There are times where I don't get  so there should be a check for that as well.

any solution on this?

At times we are getting  inside body as well. So is there any way to remove that part off?

for example

```
var str = "<html><head><title>SomeTitle</title></head><style>a.hover{color:green}cc.a{color:red},pq.a{text-decoration:underline}</style> <body> <style>.hello12{color:green}</style>Some content </body></html>";
```

and i should get just "some content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and get text content from `body` tag. Where [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) can be used to get `body` element and get text content from [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

```js
var str = "<html><head><title>SomeTitle</title></head><style>a.hover{color:green}cc.a{color:red},pq.a{text-decoration:underline}</style> <body> Some content </body></html>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");

console.log(
  doc.querySelector('body').textContent
)
```

---

**FYI :** To avoid `script` and `style` tag content use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) property instead of [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

Comment: this works! but will the tags inside the body be displayed in the final text as well?

Comment: okay thats cool! so this will completly avoid all the other tags right? Awsm solution. Thanks!

Comment: @AnilSimon :  but it would contain the text within the tag

Comment: so what if the body contains <style> ? Is there any way to remove that part  off alone?

Comment: @AnilSimon :  then use `innerText`

Comment: even using innerText is giving me the text inside the style

Comment: i just need a solution to chip off the style part with the contents alone from the body string

Comment: @AnilSimon : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText or otherways iterate and remove the style and script tag by iterating